# How to en-queue javascript that have dependency on jquery?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to enqueue my custom javascript code in WordPress' functions.php file,
I am doing the following,

```
function background_animation_script() {
    wp_register_script('background_animation', plugins_url('/assets/js/jquery.backgroundPosition.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'),'1.0', true);
}

function hero_animation_script() {
    wp_register_script('hero_animation', plugins_url('/assets/js/background-animation.js', __FILE__), array('jquery','background_animation_script'), '1.0', true);
}

function custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('background_animation_script');
    wp_enqueue_script('hero_animation_script');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts');
```

But, for some reason, the custom scripts are not getting loaded onto the page, but the jquery is. Any help with this is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use the below function for add jquery in plugin**

```
    function custom_scripts() {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'background_animation_script', plugins_url('/assets/js/jquery.backgroundPosition.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'),'1.0', true);
       wp_enqueue_script( 'hero_animation', plugins_url('/assets/js/background-animation.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts');
```